# Search button not inline with input field

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on a Bootstrap 3 navigation bar and can't figure out how to keep the search button next to the input at small resolutions. Please let me know if you need more details. Thanks!

```
codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOQJKp?editors=100
```

Large screen (looks good):
[image: large screen]

Small screen:

[image]

HTML:

```
 <div class="container">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>


        </div>


        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>

            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> Pages <strong class="caret"></strong></a>

              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">page 2</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>

              </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
              <form class="navbar-form pull-left" action="#">
                <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="" id="searchInput">
                <button type="submit" name="sa" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
              </form>

            </li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Account <strong class="caret"></strong></a>

              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Address</a></li>
              </ul>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>



      </div>

    </nav>


  </div>
```

Comment: why not puting it as an addon?
I am using bootstrap 3 to a certain extend, i can help. add your html code

Comment: codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOQJKp?editors=100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

[example](http://js.do/code/64123)

put this inside the form.
I should thank you because I was looking to do the same for my page, thanks to you i found it

Answer (score 1):

Add it as a button group:

```
 <div class="row">

 <div class="col-lg-6">
 <div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
  </span>
 </div><!-- /input-group -->
</div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ntcp5zme/